# События в c# без event

Tags: c#

Господа, скажите пожалуйста, для чего использовать ключевое слово event в объявлении события, если события - это те же самые делегаты ? Вроде все прекрасно можно реализовать и без event.
По сути объявление поля события - это объявление переменной делегата, в которую в дальнейшем внедряются методы. И соответственно при вызове этого события происходит групповой вызов методов
Спасибо.

Comment: [Коротко][1]
[Поподробнее][2]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/65697/
  [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/198694/

Comment: Обсуждалось [тут](/questions/226505/) когда-то.